# MySQL count rows on multiple grouped columns

Tags: mysql

I have a following structure on my MySQL tables:

```
-------------------------------------------
                 Goal
-------------------------------------------
GoalID  |  GameID  |  ScorerID  |  AssistID
-------------------------------------------
   1          1          1            2
   2          1          2            3
   3          1          2           null
   4          1          3            2
   5          2          1            3
   6          2          1           null


----------------------
       Player
----------------------
PlayerID  |  LastName
----------------------
   1            AB    
   2            CD  
   3            EF
```

now, what I want to achieve is the following:

```
-------------------------------------------
GameID  |  Player  |  Goals  |  Assists
-------------------------------------------
   1         AB          1         0
   1         CD          2         2
   1         EF          1         1
   2         AB          2         0
   2         EF          0         1
```

This is what I have tried but it gives me the wrong results:

```
SELECT Goal.GoalID,
   Goal.GameID,
   COUNT(Scorer.PlayerID) AS Goals,
   COUNT(Assist.PlayerID) AS Assists,
   Player.LastName AS Player
FROM Goal
LEFT JOIN Player Player
       ON Player.PlayerID = Goal.ScorerID
       OR Player.PlayerID = Goal.AssistID
LEFT JOIN Player Scorer
       ON Scorer.PlayerID = Goal.ScorerID
LEFT JOIN Player Assist
       ON Assist.PlayerID = Goal.AssistID
GROUP BY Player,
         Goal.GameID
ORDER BY Goal.GameID,
         Goal.GoalID
```

I'm pretty sure there's a simple way to get the result but I just can't get my head around this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using conditional aggregation. To do so, you join the player and goal tables on the condition that the player id matches the scorerid or assist id, and then get the SUM() of situations where the player id is in the score or assist column, and ultimately group by gameID and playerID. Like this:

```
SELECT g.gameID, p.lastName AS Player, SUM(g.scorerID = p.playerID) AS goals, SUM(g.assistID = p.playerID) AS assists
FROM goal g
JOIN player p ON p.playerID = g.scorerID OR p.playerID = g.assistID
GROUP BY g.gameID, p.playerID;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4e2e/1) example.

It is important to note that this example assumes the player has at least one goal or at least one assist. If you want players who have neither, you can use an outer join.

Comment: @StuartLC thanks, I didn't know that! Thankfully OP only had eight rows, so I hope I was able to type them in time to get my answer noticed ;)

Comment: Looks solid... what do you mean by "assumes the player has at least one goal or at least one assist"

Comment: If you have a player in the players table who doesn't appear at all in the goals table, they won't be returned by my query. To do that, you can just change it from JOIN to RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: ahh.. ok... that was kind of one of the questions that could have been read between the lines. :D

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88479/7

```
SELECT g.GameID, 
  p.LastName, 
  SUM(IF(p.id=g.ScorerID,1,0)) as Goals, 
  SUM(IF(p.id=g.AssistID,1,0)) as Assists
FROM goal g
LEFT JOIN player p
ON p.id = g.ScorerID
  OR p.id = g.AssistID
GROUP BY g.GameID,p.id
```

Comment: Good answer, a lot cleaner than having several subqueries and joins. Just a comment, MySQL will allow you to do `SUM(condition)` to get counts. So if you said `SUM(p.id = g.scorerID)` it will return the same as `SUM(IF(p.id=g.scorerID,1,0))`

Comment: Agree with you. That is just my way of logic `a=b` return boolean in my mind, so I'am just do it to be sure what type do I `SUM`

Comment: Of course, I just thought i'd mention it in case you weren't familiar with it. Anytime you can save a few key strokes to achieve the same result is a good thing to me, haha!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to `CROSS JOIN` players and goals, and then count the number of intersections on `Scorers` and `Assists` using a `CASE..WHEN` mapping. `HAVING` is used to eliminate players who haven't contributed to the scoreline.

```
SELECT
   Goal.GameID,
   Player.LastName AS Player,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Goal.ScorerId = Player.PlayerID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Goals,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Goal.AssistId = Player.PlayerID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Assists
FROM Goal
CROSS JOIN Player
GROUP BY Player.LastName,
         Goal.GameID
HAVING Goals > 0 OR Assists > 0
ORDER BY Goal.GameID,
         Player.LastName;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12da9/8)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this. I believe something like this would work fine:

```
SELECT
    GameId,
    Lastname,
    Sum(Goals) as Goals,
    Sum(Assists) as Assists
FROM
    (
        SELECT GameID, Player.Lastname, 1 as Goals, 0 as Assists
        FROM Goal 
            INNER JOIN Player ON goal.scorerID = Player.PlayerID

        UNION

        SELECT GameID, Player.Lastname, 0 as Goals, 1 as Assists
        FROM Goal 
            INNER JOIN Player ON goal.AssistID = Player.PlayerID

    ) Games
GROUP BY GameID, LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is quite simple way to achieve this:

```
select GameId, LastName, goals, assist
from
(
    select GameId, player, sum(goals) as goals, sum(assist) as assist
    from
    (
        select GameId, ScorerId as player, count(*) as goals, 0 as assist
        from Goal
        group by GameId, ScorerId
        union all
        select GameId, AssistId, 0 as goals, count(*) as assist
        from Goal
        where AssistId is not null
        group by GameId, AssistId
    ) as q
    group by GameId, player
) as q2
inner join
Player as t
on (q2.player=t.PlayerId)
order by GameId, LastName
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b135a/5